# when I render an Animation it shows up completely Blank

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am using Blender 2.80. I finished a blender scene and hit ctrl f12 to render. the result is completely black and it spits out all 100 frames in a couple of seconds.i have looked at a lot of troubleshooting pages and none of them have helped fix the situation. i have a spotlight at the camera, world brightness settings are over 1, i know the camera is not obstructed. it also appears that any other blender file I have that has previously rendered before wont do so now. any help would be great, thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does your scene have any lights in it, what is you background intensity? Make sure that Rendered Layers are conncted to the Composite in your compositor. I assume you're using eevee with this kind of render speed. Would be useful to see your scene.

Comment: Can you share details of your setup? If you can render the default cube and view it, then you might have to check that the compositor and VSE are set up correctly.

Comment: Gtx 1660ti i7 9th gen, 16 gigs of ram. I cant render any scenes at all on any blender files. It could be a bug but im not sure

Comment: Are you using the latest cuda drivers from nvidia for GPU rendering? Is CPU rendering working? What happens when you reset blender to factory settings and press F12?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the blender file had become corrupted. I restarted the computer and opened a new file and tried the animation. I was able to copy objects over and finish the animation, thanks for all the help!!